# angularJS conditionally redirect a user

Tags: angularjs

I am using Auth0 in my app to check (in the template) if a user is authenticated.  Something like:

```
<div ng-if="isAuthenticated" id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-importer class="grid" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-selection ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-paging myscroller></div>
<div ng-if="!isAuthenticated">
  <p>You will be redirected because you are not authenticated</p>
</div>
```

in the `!isAuthenticated` section, how can I redirect a user from inside the HTML? Is there a way?

I have seen something like this before: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=http://www.redirectedsite.com">` but this doesnt seem to apply, as it's a meta tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngInit`

```
<div ng-if="isAuthenticated" id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-importer class="grid" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-selection ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-paging myscroller></div>
<div ng-if="!isAuthenticated">
  <p ng-init="redirect()">You will be redirected because you are not authenticated</p>
</div>
```

in Controller:

```
$scope.redirect = function() {
    // redirecting in 1 sec...
    $timeout(function() {
        $location.path('/login');
    }, 1000); 
}
```